# Rails: sum should retun nil if given column values is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently sum function in Rails return 0.0, if provided columns data is null

============================================================================

For example: 
Tablename: Price

```
id | name | Cost
-----------------
1  |  A   | 1200

2  |  A   | 2500

3  |  A   | 3000

4  |  B   | 5000

5  |  B   | 7000

6  |  C   |
```

Now,

```
Price.group(:name).sum(:cost)
```

return `6700`, `12000`, `0.0` , instead of `6700`, `12000`, `nil`.

So here I want nil if given columns value is 'null' or empty

Comment: What's stopping you from adding code to present `nil` if the sum is `0`?

Comment: Why do you want `nil` ?

Comment: what DB you are using..? May be then I can help you.

Comment: @jcm if there is actual cost is 0.0 then setting nil for sum=0 is meaningless

Comment: @ArupRakshit I want nil for csv data an graph presentation I am using mysql and in mysql this query return result as per my requirment means it retuns nil for cost value null

Comment: @Kanti okay, got it.  Maybe you should add that to the question.

Comment: Just write code to replace 0 with nil when you get the results from `sum`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUM` is ignoring null values, so columns with `NULL` values will always be `0` as `zero + nothing` is `0`

To overcome this I have used condition like:

```
Price.where("cost IS NOT NULL).group(:name).sum(:cost)
```

This request will get non null cost values and sum them. After that, I can fill with `NULL` the cost columns of the other records.

This way I can make sure that if cost is actually `0.0` then I get `sum(cost)` as `0.0` instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Due to [the implementation of `sum` in Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb#L327), it is impossible to get the values before type cast.

However, you can get the expected values by selecting the values with raw SQL:

```
Price.group(:name).select('name, sum(cost) AS total_cost')
```